# Disk write performance drops with write happening in multiple directories

Tags: c, filesystems, storage

I have storage with XFS file system.

**Scenario 1**:

- continuously writing multiple files in a single directory
  ex: All files are written in `/mnt/storage/test/` directory

**Scenario 2**:

- continuously writing multiple files in multiple directories

In **iteration 1**:

- file is saved in `/mnt/storage/test/repeat1/` directory

In **iteration 2**:

- file is saved in `/mnt/storage/test/repeat2/` directory

With **Scenario 1**, disk write performance observed is constant.
with **Scenario 2**, disk write performance is seen as saw tooth pattern. as the number of directory increases the write performance drops.

Any idea why XFS performance varies with file write in multiple directories?

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: this is not a perfect answer:

The XFS allocates a directory in blocks.  All writes to the same directory go to the same block (and generally the disk heads are already on the correct cylinder.)

the actual writes are performed in bursts.

A new/different directory is in a different block.

When making alternating directory writes the disk heads must be moved to the appropriate block at each directory change.  To minimize the disk head movements, multiple writes to one directory are collected and written in a burst.